# How can I get an element of a particular index from a set in GAMS?

Tags: indexing, set, gams-math

Suppose I have the set ``codes" in GAMS:

```
SET    
      codes /aaa, aab, aac, aad, aae/;
```

How can I then say get the 3rd element (or any element) in the set in GAMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the "ord" operator like this?

```
SET
      codes /aaa, aab, aac, aad, aae/
      selected(codes);

selected(codes) = ord(codes)=3;

Display selected;
```

Comment: Yes! That's precisely what I am looking for. Thank you :)